# How to test time-dependent methods?

Tags: testing, time

**What's the standard/recommended way to test time-dependent methods?**

As an example:

I have a class `Foo` that has a method `GetTimestamp()` and `GetTimestamp()` should return the given time in a `string` that always increases lexicographically (alphabetical sort order).

What's the best way to test this without overengineering for testing purposes?

My initial thought was to create a class constructor that accepts an `IDateTimeProvider` whose only property was a `DateTime` property, and then from the unit test I could create a dummy DateTimeProvider...

This is a simplistic case but represents what I'm wondering about.

This has a lot of other applications, such as testing date-dependent logic around leap years, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good resource:

[Why there is no IDateTimeProvider in .NET and DateTime has Now getter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131702/why-there-is-no-idatetimeprovider-in-net-and-datetime-has-now-getter)

It sounds like this is an OK approach.

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do is create a public function that returns a DateTime (`Func<DateTime>`) in the class that needs the current date/time and set the it to return `DateTime.Now` by default. Then, during testing, I inject a testing function that returns whatever DateTime I want to test with.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Func<DateTime> DateTimeNow = () => DateTime.Now;

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var currentTime = DateTimeNow();
        //... do work
    }
}

public class MyClassTest
{
    public void TesttMyMethod()
    {
        // Arrange
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.DateTimeNow = () => new DateTime(1999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);

        // Act
        myClass.MyMethod();

        // Assert
        // my asserts
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh, that was a 3 year old question!  Things have changed since then.  Nice approach.  There's also this approach that I read about a couple weeks ago: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx